# Uncaught ReferenceError: username is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, email, registration

> Uncaught ReferenceError: username is not defined     at register.html?username=Petra+Meier&email=petra%40meier.de&password=1234598&repeat_password=123459:126 (anonym) @ register.html?username=Petra+Meier&email=petra%40meier.de&password=1234598&repeat_password=123459:126

The problem is within `data`

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "p.php",
  data: {
    signUp_username: username, 
    signUp_email: email, 
    signUp_pass: password, 
    pass_again: password_proof
  }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800');
```

```js
$('#switch_login').click(function() {
  location.href = "http://localhost/Manage/dujic/login_3.html?#";
});

$('#register').click(function() {
  $debug = false;

  username = $('#signUp_username').val();
  console.log(username);

  email = $('#signUp_email').val();
  console.log(email);

  password = $('#signUp_pass').val();
  console.log(password);

  repeat_password = $('#pass_again').val();
  console.log(repeat_password);

  //1  
  if (!isUsername(username)) {
    if ($debug)
      displayMessageBox('#message', 'Bitte gültige Username eintragen!');

    $('#signUp_username').focus();
    $('#signUp_username').css('background-color:red');
    return;
  }

  //2
  if (!isEmail(email)) {
    if ($debug)
      displayMessageBox('#message', 'Bitte gültige E-Mail eintragen!');

    $('#signUp_email').focus();
    $('#signUp_email').css('background-color:red');
    return;
  }

  //3
  if (!isPassword(password)) {
    if ($debug)
      displayMessageBox('#message', 'Bitte gültiges Kennwort eintragen!');

    $('#signUp_pass').focus();
    $('#signUp_pass').css('background-color:red');
    return;
  }

  //4
  if (!isPassword_proof(password_proof)) {
    if ($debug)
      displayMessageBox('#message', 'Bitte gültiges Kennwort eintragen!');

    $('#pass_again').focus();
    $('#pass_again').css('background-color:red');
    return;
  }

  if (isUsername(username) && isEmail(email) && isPassword(password) && isPassword_proof(repeat_password)) {
    if ($debug)
      displayMessageBox('#message', '');

    $('#signUp_username').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#signUp_email').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#signUp_pass').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#pass_again').css('background-color', 'white');

    if ($('#message').is(":visible")) {
      $('#message').toggle();
    }
  }
})

$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "p.php",
  data: {
    signUp_username: username,
    signUp_email: email,
    signUp_pass: password,
    pass_again: password_proof
  }
}).done(function(msg) {
  if ($debug) displayMessageBox('#message', msg);
  if (msg == true) {
    location.href = 'http://localhost/Manage/login_3.html?#';
  } else {
    displayMessageBox('#message', 'Sign In failed');
  }
});

function isUsername(username) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(username);
}

function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}

function isPassword(password) {
  if (password == "" || password.length < 4) {
    return false;
  } else {
    var regex = /[A-Za-z0-9_]/;
    return regex.test(password);
  }
}

function isPassword_proof(password_proof) {
  if (password == "" || password.length < 4) {
    return false;
  } else {
    var regex = /[A-Za-z0-9_]/;
    return regex.test(password);
  }
}

function displayMessageBox(boxName, BoxContent) {
  if ($(boxName).is(':hidden')) {
    $(boxName).toggle();
  }
  $(boxName).text(BoxContent);
}
```

Comment: declare your local variables using `let` or `const`: `const username = $('#signUp_username').val();console.log(username);`, `const email = ...`, etc.

Comment: Also, as `username`, `email`, etc. are declared inside the `onClick()` function for `#register`, they are not available in the scope of the AJAX call.

Comment: The AJAX call is not in the same scope as the block of code you set `username` in. Also note that you should use declare the variable using `var`, `let` or `const` (depending on use case), but that is not the problem, as the answers below suggest.

Comment: ok i will try thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var username = $('#signUp_username').val();console.log(username);
var email = $('#signUp_email').val(); console.log(email);
var password = $('#signUp_pass').val();console.log(password);
var repeat_password = $('#pass_again').val();console.log(repeat_password);



<input type ="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="signUp_username" />
<input type ="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="signUp_email" />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="signUp_pass" /> 
<input type="password" name="repeat_password" placeholder="Password_proof" id="pass_again" />
```

Comment: Without the `var` declaration the variable will be declared in `window` scope, so that's not the problem. The issue is that the AJAX call is not in the same block of code as the `click` event handler.

Comment: As it is now, that code would not even work as the JavaScript code is not within a `<script></script>` tag and, even if it were, you would be trying to access DOM elements before they are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

declare username, email... etc outside the function.

then use: `username = $('#signUp_username').val();` inside